# AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean() not working

Tags: java, spring, autowired

In my spring.xml I have a few beans:

```
<bean id="WorkerA" class="..."></bean>
<bean id="WorkerB" class="..."></bean>

<bean id="ServiceA" class="..."></bean>
<bean id="ServiceB" class="..."></bean>
```

These classes all extend an `abstract class Worker`:

```
public abstract class Worker {
    abstract void doSomething ();
}
```

and include different `@Autowired` services like so:

```
public class WorkerA extends Worker {
    @Autowired ServiceA serviceA;

    public void doSomething () {
        serviceA.foo();
    }
}
```

I am trying to instantiate these beans using `AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean()` as shown:

```
Worker worker = workerFactory.create(); // creates a WorkerA
beanFactory.autowireBean(worker);
worker.doSomething();
```

However I am getting NullPointerExceptions on the line calling `serviceA.foo()`, so clearly ServiceA is not being Autowired. Is this due to Spring attempting to Autowire a `Worker` class for which there is no bean definition instead of the appropriate `WorkerX`? Am I misubnderstanding something?

Comment: If you already *have* your beans defined in the context, why are you creating new ones?

Comment: Add `<context:annotation-config />` to your XML configuration (unless you already have a `<context:component-scan />` already.

Comment: ah thank you! `<context:annotation-config/>` fixed me right up

Comment: @chrylis most of my beans are defined in the "normal" way. These though are not singletons and are created a few layers down programmatically. I wanted to inject their dependencies programmatically as well using `autowireBean()` rather than pass a whole slew of dependencies throughout the different levels of the code. Especially since doing so would not allow me to simply use the abstract superclass to simplify things (as the different subclasses can have different dependencies)